# What technology is used to implement tiny glade

Tags: game-development

I am interested in [Tiny Glade](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2198150/Tiny_Glade/) and wanted to know what technology it was implemented with, especially the auto-generation feature in it,  What areas of expertise does it contain
please someone who knows tell me how to achieve the similar functions

Comment: Look here https://steamcommunity.com/app/2198150/discussions/0/3709306945109116212/ and here https://howtomarketagame.com/2023/06/12/marketing-your-steam-game-before-you-have-a-steam-page-the-tiny-glade-story/: `We’re using our own home-made engine written in the Rust language. At some point, we were wondering - are we crazy? Well, yes! But the game uses so much custom technology that we concluded it was actually a pretty sane choice :) We also benefit from a lot of open source software, including Bevy's Entity Component System (ECS).`